# How does Nessus detect CVE's in scans

Tags: nessus

how does Nessus scanner write plugins for the latest CVE’s that don’t have a public exploit? in order to identify the vulnerabilities in the network. does it do banner matching with the available CVE ?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases a version check will be done using either local or remote detection to verify if the target version is vulnerable.

In other cases a security researcher will work on developing a proof of concept based on the vulnerability description.